# Live jQuery table row count

Tags: jquery, count, html-table, row

I have a table that is dynamically changed via jQuery (it can be searched which if the search criteria is met it will remove the non matching rows)

What I would like is a row count which i have got by using:

```
var rowCount = $("#table tr").length - 1;
$('a#rowcount').click(function() {
alert(rowCount);
});
```

However if I do a search and the `<tr>`'s go from say 30 to just 4 matching results clicking rowcount will still show 30.

Is there a way to make the row count dynamic?

Comment: after the search finished you need to recall the call count `rowCount = $("#table tr").length - 1;`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$('a#rowcount').click(function() {
  alert($("#table tr").length - 1);
});
```

Your rowCount variable was scoped outside of the click function, so it will never be updated.

[See here for jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WUT8/12/)

Comment: unfortunately gives the same result

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
$('a#rowcount').click(function() {
    alert(rowCount);
});
```

Will not work on dynamically loaded elements. If you want rowCount to be recalculated every time you click the `rowcount` link, you should do that calculation inside the function. If the number of rows in your table change dynamically with ajax, you need to use on() to count the newly added rows:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#rowcount', function()
{
   var rowCount = $("#table tr").length - 1;
   alert(rowCount);
});
```

Comment: on() is only as of the newest version of jQuery (1.7)...what version are you using?

Comment: @CHawk, did not know about `jQuery.on()`. Thanks for sharing. +1